# How to retrieve all value from firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

DATABASE

[image]

I wanted to retrieve all the value from my firebase, but it retrieved the last one only which is "hjh" , what did i do wrong?

This is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("content");
ArrayList<String> postList = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference contentRef = rootRef.child("Post");
ValueEventListener value_l;
TextView content_view;
ListView listview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //setContentView(R.layout.post_info);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    content_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contentTextview);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);


    value_l = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String contentText = ds.child("content").getValue(String.class);
                postList.add(contentText);
                //FOR ARRAYLIST TESTING content_view.setText(postList.get(postList.size()-1));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    };
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you print "Log.d("Testing", contentText);"?

Comment: oh it shows all the value okay, but i can't show it all the value in textview, only the last one

Comment: Do you want to show that array in the listview with textview?

Comment: So you basically say that when you uncomment that line, you only set the last value to the `content_view`, right? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: yesss @AlexMamo

Comment: yesss @phonemyatt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this code it may be help you.

1) MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rvData;
    private RetriveDataAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rvData = findViewById(R.id.rvData);
        rvData.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvData.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

        DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        database.child("Post").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<MyBean> arrayList = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
                for (DataSnapshot noteDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    MyBean bean = noteDataSnapshot.getValue(MyBean.class);
                    arrayList.add(bean);
                }
                Log.e("MainActivity.this", "Data list ::>>>>>" + arrayList.size());
                adapter = new RetriveDataAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
                rvData.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

2) MyBean

```
public class MyBean {

    public String content;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

3) RetriveDataAdapter

```
public class RetriveDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RetriveDataAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "RetriveDataAdapter.class";
    private Context ctx;
    private ArrayList<MyBean> dataList;

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    public RetriveDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyBean> dataList) {
        this.ctx = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvContent;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            tvContent = view.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_form, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
         final MyBean bean = dataList.get(position);

        holder.tvContent.setText("Content: " + bean.getContent());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i have my own adapter and my own "MyBean" but the problem was, it didn't show the value in list view, fortunately I managed to fix that by putting the setAdapter inside the "onDataChange", it fixed, but there is another problem, everytime I add another data to firebase from my app, the values which has been shown are repeated, how do i fix this? @Kinjal

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your whole Database's structure and didn't see where you call `addValueEventListener(value_l)` , so that I can only guess it's because of the wrong level `Reference`.

You should add `value_l` to the correct reference, maybe all the post's parent, and iterate through all of it's child using `snapshot.forEach()`

Google for `firebase database iterate` may provides more detailed information.

Comment: i updated the image and how do i fix this? I think i put the code correctly and follow the rules from the internet, but it only show the last value from my database